# Firebase AngularFire nested collections

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have data of the form

```
{
  "events" : {
    "-J2MoqWZnkcRCSugBfj3" : {
      "title" : "Some other event",
      "ratings" : {
        "-J2N4QYSk4y2BYznkGvk" : {
          "value" : 0
        },
        "-J2N3rfUPlPNP45RUZYx" : {
          "value" : 0
        }
      }
    },
    "-J2MpSSN8oldDqd-0jrr" : {
      "title" : "New event"
    }
  }
}
```

The events collection has a nested collection called ratings. I wish to manage both the collections through **angularFireCollection**, but I am not sure how do I get around to do it.

My Angular controller and template are defined as:

```
APP.controller('EventsCtrl', function ($scope, angularFireCollection) {

    $scope.events = angularFireCollection(<reference to events collection>);

});


<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-controller="IndividualEventCtrl" ng-repeat="event in events">
    <div><strong class="lead">{{event.title}}</strong></div>
    <div ng-include="event.template"></div>
    <rating value="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly"></rating>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller for each event:

```
APP.controller('IndividualEventCtrl', function ($scope, FirebaseService, angularFireCollection) {
    $scope.max = 5;
    $scope.rate = 0;
    $scope.isReadonly = false;

    var ratingsRef = FirebaseService.events().child($scope.event.$id).child("ratings");
    $scope.rating = ratingsRef.push({value:0});

});
```

The last two lines where I create the `ratingsRef` and add a new rating to the collection cause my controller to go in some sort of an infinite loop.

I'd really like to know what is the best way to manage nested collections so that I can add/update the elements in those collections.

Comment: Why not create a single collection for the top-level events list and simply edit each rating within that collection? Why do you need to create a separate collection for the ratings?